# Can not update custom fonts

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

> I am working on a website for which i used custom fonts but i am not able use it in my website. Am i using it correctly?

```css
.pattern{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.5) url(../images/pattern.png);
 padding-top:100px;
 font: AmaticSC-Bold;
 font-family: AmaticSC;
}
```

Comment: how have you loaded the font ?

Comment: Are you using an `@import` to get the font? How does the browser know where to get `Amatic` from? Please post your code relevant to that as well.

Comment: Add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" /> in header and then in style.css use font-family: 'Amatic SC';  http://www.cssfontstack.com/Amatic-SC....Else download fonts (ttf,otf etc) and include fonts in style.css

Answer (score 0):

In html, there are a fixed set of font-family that you can use without adding the necessary files and importing them into your stylesheet. I am not sure if AmaticSC-Bold is the name of the font or that you are trying to bold it. If you are trying to bold it, use the `font-weight:bold` tag. If you would like more fonts to try out on: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/